# Generate dates without gap and vlookup 2 tables

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 tables,
Table 1 - has the available principal balance on the transaction dates

=>(Transactions_Date, Principal balance)

Table 2 - has interest rates and the effective dates

=> ( Effective_Date, Interest)

I have to generate a result set, with the below data

1. Result_Date - List out all the dates from table1(Transaction_Date) by filling all the gaps between the available dates
2. Principle Balance - vlookup the Result_Dates in Table 1 and fill in the corresponding Principal_Balance until the next table1.transaction_date.
3. Interest - vlookup Result_date in Table 2.Effective_date and fill in all the Interest for that date range.

How to implement this in SNOWFLAKE?

Note: I can use CTE but can not create table

Answer (score 0):

a couple of simple steps, find the min/max of dates for all tables, find the least/greatest of those values, spread across a generator range, and then use a row_number to feed into a dateadd, then left join this range of dates to the original data, and use nvl to pick between the this value, and the carried lag via the ignore nulls extension.

```
with table_1(t_date, p_bal) as (
    select * from values
    ('2023-02-10'::date, 10000),
    ('2023-01-20'::date, 9000),
    ('2023-01-03'::date, 8000)
), table_2(e_date, interest) as (
    select * from values
    ('2023-02-05'::date, 1),
    ('2023-01-15'::date, 2),
    ('2023-01-01'::date, 3)
), range_of_date as (
    select dateadd(day, rn, min_date) as date 
    from (
        select 
            least(min_t_date, min_e_date) as min_date
            ,greatest(max_t_date, max_e_date) as max_date
        from (
            select 
                min(t_date) as min_t_date
                ,max(t_date) as max_t_date
            from table_1
        ) as t
        cross join (
            select 
                min(e_date) as min_e_date
                ,max(e_date) as max_e_date
            from table_2
        ) as e
    ) as a
    cross join (
        select 
            row_number() over (order by null) - 1 as rn
        from table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 1000))
    ) as b
    having date <= max_date
)
select 
    *
    ,nvl(t1.p_bal,lag(t1.p_bal)ignore nulls over (order by rd.date)) as filled_p_bal
    ,nvl(t2.interest,lag(t2.interest)ignore nulls over(order by rd.date)) as filled_interest
from range_of_date as rd
left join table_1 as t1
    on rd.date = t1.t_date
left join table_2 as t2
    on rd.date = t2.e_date
order by 1;
```

gives:

| DATE | T_DATE | P_BAL | E_DATE | INTEREST | FILLED_P_BAL | FILLED_INTEREST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 |  |  | 2023-01-01 | 3 |  | 3 |
| 2023-01-02 |  |  |  |  |  | 3 |
| 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-03 | 8,000 |  |  | 8,000 | 3 |
| 2023-01-04 |  |  |  |  | 8,000 | 3 |
| 2023-01-05 |  |  |  |  | 8,000 | 3 |
| 2023-01-06 |  |  |  |  | 8,000 | 3 |
| 2023-01-07 |  |  |  |  | 8,000 | 3 |
| 2023-01-08 |  |  |  |  | 8,000 | 3 |
| 2023-01-09 |  |  |  |  | 8,000 | 3 |
| 2023-01-10 |  |  |  |  | 8,000 | 3 |
| 2023-01-11 |  |  |  |  | 8,000 | 3 |
| 2023-01-12 |  |  |  |  | 8,000 | 3 |
| 2023-01-13 |  |  |  |  | 8,000 | 3 |
| 2023-01-14 |  |  |  |  | 8,000 | 3 |
| 2023-01-15 |  |  | 2023-01-15 | 2 | 8,000 | 2 |
| 2023-01-16 |  |  |  |  | 8,000 | 2 |
| 2023-01-17 |  |  |  |  | 8,000 | 2 |
| 2023-01-18 |  |  |  |  | 8,000 | 2 |
| 2023-01-19 |  |  |  |  | 8,000 | 2 |
| 2023-01-20 | 2023-01-20 | 9,000 |  |  | 9,000 | 2 |
| 2023-01-21 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 2 |
| 2023-01-22 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 2 |
| 2023-01-23 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 2 |
| 2023-01-24 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 2 |
| 2023-01-25 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 2 |
| 2023-01-26 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 2 |
| 2023-01-27 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 2 |
| 2023-01-28 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 2 |
| 2023-01-29 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 2 |
| 2023-01-30 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 2 |
| 2023-01-31 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 2 |
| 2023-02-01 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 2 |
| 2023-02-02 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 2 |
| 2023-02-03 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 2 |
| 2023-02-04 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 2 |
| 2023-02-05 |  |  | 2023-02-05 | 1 | 9,000 | 1 |
| 2023-02-06 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 1 |
| 2023-02-07 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 1 |
| 2023-02-08 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 1 |
| 2023-02-09 |  |  |  |  | 9,000 | 1 |
| 2023-02-10 | 2023-02-10 | 10,000 |  |  | 10,000 | 1 |

### Take 2:

To make the data only have values in the range of the `table 1` but carry interesting values from earlier, that are not aligned with the first balance value, we need the time range to be wider (it can be a more constrained match, but I have opted for simplicity to me).

```
with table_1(t_date, p_bal) as (
    select * from values
    ('2023-02-10'::date, 10000),
    ('2023-01-20'::date, 9000),
    ('2023-01-03'::date, 8000)
), table_2(e_date, interest) as (
    select * from values
    ('2023-02-05'::date, 1),
    ('2023-01-15'::date, 2),
    ('2023-01-01'::date, 3)
), range_1 as (
    select 
        min(t_date) as min_t_date
        ,max(t_date) as max_t_date
    from table_1
), range_of_date as (
    select dateadd(day, rn, min_date) as date 
    from (
        select 
            least(min_t_date, (select min(e_date) from table_2)) as min_date
            ,max_t_date as max_date
        from range_1
    ) as a
    cross join (
        select 
            row_number() over (order by null) - 1 as rn
        from table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 1000))
    ) as b
    having date <= max_date
)
select 
    rd.date
    ,nvl(t1.p_bal,lag(t1.p_bal)ignore nulls over (order by rd.date)) as filled_p_bal
    ,nvl(t2.interest,lag(t2.interest)ignore nulls over(order by rd.date)) as filled_interest
from range_of_date as rd
left join table_1 as t1
    on rd.date = t1.t_date
left join table_2 as t2
    on rd.date = t2.e_date
qualify filled_p_bal is not null
order by 1;
```

Comment: This works for principal but not for rates as the shown result.

Comment: This works for principal but not for rates as the shown result. Can you help fix this?

Also I have modified the below part of query -- I want to take only the table1.T_date to identify the min and max date.

and can this be done without generating the rows? I'm trying to automate the query to accommodate any number of records 

select  //MODIFIED
            min(t_date) as min_date
             ,max(t_date) as max_date
        from  table_1
        ) as t

Comment: it does work for both columns. I think what is happen for you, is you don't see that value go in the direction "you expect" and that confuses "you", if you look you will see that my "test data, has the latest date first, where the results have the data oldest date first. thus the value go "in the wrong direction" but given SQL/Data has no direction. The smarts has to be done between the ears.

Comment: Sorry, your query works. The Problem I face is your query finds the greatest and least values of both T_DATE and E_DATE. But I need only the T_DATE to find the min and max dates (column1). in my case 

min(T_.Date ) = 2/1/2022 and min(E_DATE) = 2/1/2017 

So My date (column1) starts from 2/1/2017 for which there is no principal available. 
If I try to alter your code I'm not getting desired results

Comment: Right. The max / min needs to be split out into its own step. So it can be use to filter the final results once the values are projected. This could be done via a qualify and a another subselect